# c++ apls library couldn't find

Tags: c++

I download and install the ALPS computational physics library for c++,
set the PATH,
but the compiler doesn't work.

Have anyone used ALPS lib? Is there solution for this?
Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try using the full path to the header file.  Try adding `../alps/osiris/` to your PATH variable.

Comment: You need to set INCLUDE AND LIB as well as PATH.

Comment: `set the PATH` this is not enough info. We need to see the actual path you've set. Also, usually you need to set the path to `include` don't go all the way down.